# Colored text in command prompt/PowerShell is blurry

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

A troll must've mucked about with my computer during the night. I did not see this issue yesterday. It seems like only colored text is affected by this blurry madness.

What is going on and how do I fix this?

I'm using Windows 8.1.

[image: Blurry colored text]

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a problem with your screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of no error]

By blowing up the image in paint, you can see that there is a very distinct line between the dark blue background and the red text. If this is blurry to you, it may be an issue with your monitor calibration rather than the actual PowerShell config.

I would suggest checking your sharpness or pixel clock settings on your monitor.

Additionally, it may have been an update to the git client you are using, as the default for red text in PowerShell is to put it on a black background.

Comment: Hmm, it looked blurry for me in Photoshop when I was cropping the image so a monitor issue seems likely! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like git is just using a bad choice of color. It's using "dark red" instead of "red". There are two things you could try:

- [Change the colors](http://sedodream.com/2012/05/05/GitCustomizingColorsForWindowsIncludingPoshgit.aspx) that git uses.
- Run PowerShell in [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) in which you can have precise control over the individual console colors. (Supposedly you can change individual colors in the regular console, but I can't work that out.)